# Why can't I pass IList<ChildType> to F(IEnumerable<ParentType>)?

Tags: c#

I figured I could pass an `IList<ChildClass>` as an `IEnumerable<ParentClass>`, since obviously each object in a ChildType list is also an instance of ParentType.  But I'm gettin no love from the compiler.  What am I missing?

EDIT: Added function Foo3 which does what I want.  Thanks!

```
namespace StackOverflow
{
    public class ParentClass
    {
    }

    public class ChildClass : ParentClass
    {
    }

    public class Test
    {
        // works
        static void Foo(ParentClass bar2)
        {
        }

        // fails
        static void Foo2(IEnumerable<ParentClass> bar)
        {
        }

        // EDIT: here's the right answer, obtained from the 
        // Charlie Calvert blog post 
        static void Foo3<T>(IEnumerable<T> bar) where T : ParentClass
        {
        }

        public static void Main()
        {
            var childClassList = new List<ChildClass>();

            // this works as expected
            foreach (var obj in childClassList)
                Foo(obj);

            // this won't compile
            // Argument '1': cannot convert from 
            // 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ChildClass>' 
            // to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ParentClass>' 
            Foo2(childClassList);

            // EDIT: this works and is what I wanted
            Foo3(childClassList);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because generics aren't co/contra variant:

[Eric Lippert's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/16/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-one.aspx) has a great post on this.

Another article from [Charlie Calvert is here](http://blogs.msdn.com/charlie/archive/2008/10/28/linq-farm-covariance-and-contravariance-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You're missing generic variance, which doesn't exist in C# *at the moment*. Your code would work in C# 4.0, I believe.

This is a duplicate of other questions though...

See:

- [Why can't a `List<string>` be stored in a `List<object>` variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557/in-c-why-cant-a-liststring-object-be-stored-in-a-listobject-variable)
- [How does C# 4.0 Generic Covariance and Contra-Variance implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245607/how-does-c-4-0-generic-covariance-contra-variance-implmeneted)
- [Is there a way to cast generic lists to lists of interface/base class types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188769/is-there-a-way-to-cast-generic-lists-to-lists-of-interface-base-class-types)
- [C# .NET passing a collection of InterfaceImplementingClass objects to a routine that takes a collection of Interface objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584319)
- [Casting from `IEnumerable<Object>` to `IEnumerable<String>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609608)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584319  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/609608

Comment: That's not fair! You can't call duplicate without a link. Now I must hurry to find it before Jon does.

Comment: I know it's not an *exact* duplicate of any of those, but I'm still adding a "close" vote.

Comment: @Matt: I'll add your two different ones to my list.

Answer (score 1):

You should find all you're looking for in [Eric Lippert's Covariance and Contravariance series](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/tags/Covariance+and+Contravariance/default.aspx). It's a fair bit of reading, but answers (a) why you can't do this in C# 3.0, and (b) why you will be able to do it i C# 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there's no implicit casting to generic parameter types (no "generic variance" seems to be the technical term). Not sure I could give you a deeper explanation, but I would just accept it as the way the CLR works...

You'll simply need to use the *Cast* extension method on childClassList to cast the list to IEnumerable.

Answer (score 0):

While in the case of IList and IEnumerable things would work out OK, the compiler has no way of really knowing that when you see it as collection and collection.

If you could use a collection as a collection somebody could try add a Parent to the collection ... the compiler has to prevent this.