# C# Cannot convert from IEnumerable<Base> to IEnumerable<Derived>

Tags: c#, inheritance, collections, ienumerable

I recently run into trouble when trying to AddRange(IEnumerable) to a List. Probably a classic issue, but I do not really get it yet.

I understand that methods expecting a List parameter are not satisfied with a List, because they might try to add a Base to the List, which is obviously impossible.

But if i get this correctly, since IEnumerables themselves cannot be changed, it ought to work in this case.

The code i thought of looks like this:

```
class Foo
{
}

class Bar : Foo
{
}

class FooCol
{
    private List<Foo> m_Foos = new List<Foo> ();

    public void AddRange1(IEnumerable<Foo> foos)
    {
        m_Foos.AddRange (foos); // does work
    }

    public void AddRange2<T>(IEnumerable<T> foos) where T : Foo
    {
        m_Foos.AddRange (foos); // does not work
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FooCol fooCol = new FooCol ();

        List<Foo> foos = new List<Foo> ();
        List<Bar> bars = new List<Bar> ();

        fooCol.AddRange1 (foos); // does work
        fooCol.AddRange1 (bars); // does not work

        fooCol.AddRange2 (foos); // does work
        fooCol.AddRange2 (bars); // does work
    }
}
```

I tried to pass a hint to the compiler in the AddRange2 method, but this just moved to problem around.

Is my way of thinking flawed? Is this a limitation of the language or is it by design?

IIRC, support for this kind of operations was added to Java 1.5, so maybe it will be added to C# at some point in the future, too...?

Comment: Duplicate of various other questions, including most recently http://stackoverflow.com/questions/632399

Comment: This seems to be (effectively) a duplicate of [this recent SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/632399/why-cant-i-pass-ilistchildtype-to-fienumerableparenttype/632415#632415).

Comment: Indeed, i'm sorry. My google-jutsu still needs improvement.

Comment: No problem. It would be nice to have a per-tag FAQ, IMO...

Comment: @Jon - not a bad idea; one for UserVoice? The ability to have a per-tag landing page (wiki editable) where we can put this type of thing...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/pages/general/suggestions/138261-allow-a-per-tag-home-faq-page

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is covariance, and will be fixed in C# 4.0 / .NET 4.0. For now, the generic option is  the best answer (for `IEnumerable<T>` - [not `IList<T>` etc](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2009/02/what-c-40-covariance-doesn-do.html)).

But within the generic method, you have to think in terms of `T`. You could also use `Cast<T>` or `OfType<T>` with LINQ to achieve something similar.

Comment: Thank you for the new term, covariance.  Didn't know about the existence.

Answer (score 2):

In C# 3.0 you can use the "Cast" extension method. If you import System.Linq and then use this code:

```
public void AddRange2<T>(IEnumerable<T> foos) where T : Foo
{
    m_Foos.AddRange (foos.Cast<Foo>());
}
```

Then it should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

There is workaround with extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<TBase> ToBaseEnumerable<TBase, TDerived>( this IEnumerable<TDerived> items ) where TDerived : TBase {
    foreach( var item in items ) {
        yield return item;
    }
}
...
IEnumerable<Employee> employees = GetEmployees(); //Emplyoee derives from Person
DoSomethingWithPersons( employees.ToBaseEnumerable<Person, Employee>() );
```

but the "<Person, Employee>" is little bit awkward :/.

Answer (score 0):

The cast solution of course might generated class cast exceptions.
The person who posted the enumerable extension work around said it was awkward.
I came up with a solution which is only half as awkward, don't know if I'll use it:

```
public static class UpTo<T>
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> From<F>(IEnumerable<F> source) where F:T
    {
        // this cast is guaranteed to work
        return source.Select(f => (T) f);
    }
}
```

Usage:

IEnumerable mammals = UpTo<Mammal>.From(kennel.Dogs)