# A Solution For (IEnumerable<Base>)Derive; Yet?

Tags: c#, .net, list, ienumerable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# Cannot convert from IEnumerable<Base> to IEnumerable<Derived>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634268/c-cannot-convert-from-ienumerablebase-to-ienumerablederived)

I have D1 and D2 which derive from B. When i write `var ls = (IEnumerable<B>)(cond?lsD1:lsD2);` I get a runtime cast error. IIRC this is a well known problem. My question is

1) Is this allowed yet? perhaps in .NET 4? I have 2010 but my project is a few months old, large and targets 3.5.

2) Is there a simple workaround? I only need to read the list not add anything or remove. Actually, ToArray() would probably work but is there another solution?

Comment: It's called covariance in .NET 4, this is more or less a dupe - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/634268/c-cannot-convert-from-ienumerablebase-to-ienumerablederived

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So if I'm reading your question correctly, this is an example of [covarience](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/csharpfaq/covariance-and-contravariance-faq).  C# 4 supports this for some interfaces IEnumerable being one of them.

The workaround in C# 3 would probably be something along the lines of:

```
var ls = (IEnumerable<B>)(cond ? lsD1.Cast<B>() : lsD2.Cast<B>());
```

Turning them into arrays would also work, but only because variance is ["broken" (see section: Broken array variance)](http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2009/04/13/c-4-0-feature-focus-part-4-generic-co-and-contra-variance-for-delegate-and-interface-types.aspx) for arrays.

Answer (score 3):

I believe your best bet is to use the `Cast<T>` extension on the lists. Something like

```
var ls = cond ? lsD1.Cast<B>() : lsD2.Cast<B>();
```